# Environment variables - where are they stored by linux, how do I change them and is it safe to do so?

Tags: 12.04, environment-variables

I am trying to configure a build from source an old version of gcc on my dev machine. The documentation highlight several environment variables that need to be changed in order to do this. I was wondering how to do this and also where linux stores them and if a system restart is required for any changes to be registered??

Comment: Can you list the Environment variables that need to be changed?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The **Global** environment variables of your system are stored in `/etc/environment`.
Any changes here will get reflected throughout the system and will affect all users of the system. Also, you need a Reboot, for any changes made here to take effect.

**User** level Environment variables are mostly stored in `.bashrc` and `.profile` files in your Home folder. Changes here only affect that particular user. Just close and open the terminal for configuration changes to take place.

*Edit* : If you don't want to Reboot or restart your terminal, you can make use of the source command.
Eg. `source /etc/environment` or `source .bashrc`

Comment: You don't need a reboot. You can use source command to load the variables after a change. ex: source /etc/environment or source .bashrc

Comment: For what you are trying to do changing  `.profile` in not the right thing to do. `.bashrc` should not be used as it can under some situations lead problems. And `/etc/environment` is way out (don't change the system to do one job).

Comment: if i used `source ~/.bashrc` it does word , without having to restart the terminal emulator  , but for some reason on my system i.e., elemenetary os hera , if i updated the environment on the `~/.bashrc` file using one terminal emulator , the i'll have to restart any other gui-based terminal emulator i.e., `pantheon`&`xfce` terminal emulators-even if i sourced the ~/.bashrc file- so that the change can take effect

Answer (score 2):

What you need is local temporal changes. You are not going to need them tomorrow, when you are doing something else, it may break the thing you do tomorrow. However you could save it as a build-script/makefile for use tomorrow.

```
export VARIABLE=value
export VARIABLE2=another_value
gcc …
```

or

```
VARIABLE=value VARIABLE2=another_value gcc …
```

note: If using `make`, the first example wont work. Make starts a new shell (sh) for each line.

Answer (score 2):

You should place your environment variables on a per-user basis in ~/.pam_environment

Create the file if it doesn't exist.  See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)