# Environmental variables resets after reboot

Tags: 14.04, environment-variables

I am working on PhoneGap and I need to set some Environmental variables.
I used to set it by `export` and it sets.
But when I reboot or relog then it wipes out the variables I previously exported.
I don't know why its happening...

I did :

```
 $ export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}`
 $ export PATH=${PATH}:${ANT_HOME}`
```

and similar stuff....

Please help me or provide some hints or suggestions..

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/164586/environment-variables-where-are-they-stored-by-linux-how-do-i-change-them-and

Comment: ok...then what should i write in that file? the containts.. ??

Comment: The command you used in your shell. It's explained in the second answer of the duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) is good reading on this topic.

Comment: really helpful this article

Comment: really bad answer